# Arrows alignment issue

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made the following partial drawing using Tikz:

```
\tikzset{Node/.style={minimum size = 0.5cm, inner sep = 0pt}}
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [
                ->,
                >=stealth',
                auto,node distance=3cm
            ]

            \node[Node] (1) {Phonèmes};
            \node[Node] (2) [below left = 1.0cm and 5.0cm of 1] {Voyelles};
            \node[Node] (3) [below left = 1.0cm and 1.0cm of 1] {Semi-consonnes};
            \node[Node] (4) [below right = 1.0cm and 1.0cm of 1] {Consonnes};

            \path[draw, thick]
                (1) edge node[above, midway] {} (2)
                (1) edge node[] {} (3)
                (1) edge node[] {} (4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

Which give the following image:
[image: French Phonems]

I wanted first make the 3 lines of the arrows start at the same point under the center of the word Phonèmes. Besides I would like the arrows finished above the center of the text nodes. I checked multiple topics but none of them helped me solve my issue.

Any suggestion or a comment is welcome ! Thank you in advance !

Comment: is it to hard to provide complete small document? in preamble you have information which make help you more easy! please extend your code sniped to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am sorry for this. Next time, I will provide the complete minimal code.

Comment: you still can edit your question and add missing stuff :). is my answer below useful to you?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
[
    node distance = 10mm and 10mm,
    Node/.style={minimum size = 0.5cm, inner sep = 0pt},
]

\node[Node] (1) {Phonèmes};
\node[Node] (2) [below left = of 1] {Semi-consonnes};
\node[Node] (3) [left       = of 2] {Voyelles};
\node[Node] (4) [below right= of 1] {Consonnes};

\draw[-Stealth, thick]
    (1.south) edge  (2.north)   % <-- changed
    (1.south) edge  (3.north)   % <-- changed
    (1.south)  to   (4.north);  % <-- changed
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: any news? do answer solve your problem?